# Read pdf empty and delete

Tags: nav, dynamics-al

I'm starting to program in AL language and I have a question.

How to read pdf and if it is empty delete it in business central (nav)?. The pdf is saved in a specific directory.

I can't delete it because I need a function that reads the pdf